# Delete messages in iMessage with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, imessage

Searched the entire Internet, but I could not find information on deleting sms messages in iMessage. Maybe someone will help, how to delete messages with certain `text` in the messages?

Comment: Description update, tag add

Comment: @user3439894 unfortunately my description comment was generated automatically by StackOverflow. Checking your rep I could make a conclusion about your experience with this platform. If you have a proposal - write to the support.

Comment: @Aleksey Potapov, Oh, that must be something new.